# Callback on 2 Inputs

Tags: angularjs

I have a 2 form input (firstName, lastName) and I want to check if they are unique (form validation) by querying my database. So I basically want to have a callback when two of my input elements is inputted.

What is the angular way of doing this?

I'm thinking of getting the element and using `.on('blur')` while checking if the other input is `valid` but this feels very jQuery like.

Comment: Different people will have different opinions on that

Answer (score 0):

use [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) on the inputs. 
Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    Username : <input type='text' ng-model='model.username' ng-blur='checkInputs()' /><br/>
    Password: <input type='text' ng-model='model.password' ng-blur='checkInputs()' /> <br/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.model = {username:'', password:''}; 
    $scope.checkInputs = function(){
        if($scope.model.username != '' && $scope.model.password != ''){
            if($scope.model.username == 'testuser' || $scope.model.password == 'testpass')
            {
                alert('insert unique fields!!!!')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

func will sit in your controller in this case and will have access to the username\password. You need to perform an ajax to check this, but I assume you got the point..

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hg3mm/).

Comment: And if I'm using IE < 9?

Comment: I didn't know there was a problem with this simple directive for ie < 9..but you can create your own custom on-blur directive which will use some JQuery in the worst case.

Comment: Actually ignore my comment. I didn't realize this was tagged `angularjs`. I know nothing about it